# Using SoapClient with a WCF Service (BasicHTTPBinding)

Tags: php, wcf, web-services, soap, integration

I'm trying to initialize a PHP SoapClient to call web service methods but I'm getting this Error on Initialization.
Any clue on how to trace such errors?

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:  'ISSO_CreateUser_InputMessage' already defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php(4): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://localhos...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\index.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like there is something invalid in the wsdl..

Are your service contracts valid? remember, you cannot use overrides..

Are the data contracts valid? I have seen wsdl break down if some things are tagged, such as an enumeration..

// Regards, Morten